# Double from CoreData returns very small number

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, double

I am working on a diving application, and one of the feature is to store diving's rating as double into CoreData. The interface should be able to retrieve the double value from the coredata object and then display on screen. However, the problem I got from my code is that the double returned from the object is very small (e with the power of -315). I have no idea why this is happening.

```
if let dives = self.diveSite?.logged_dives {
            for dive in dives {
                print("######### dive site info ########")
                rating = Double(dive.rating) + rating
                print(dive)
                print("raw dive site rating is \(dive.rating)")
                print("dive rating is \(rating)")
            }
        } else {
            print("no logged_dives")
        }
```

Here is what's been printed out on the console...

```
######### dive site info ########
<ScubaDoo.DiveLog: 0x7fe9ea02cbc0> (entity: DiveLog; id: 0xd000000000180002 <x-coredata://2B6F1E6F-1EDA-4910-91FA-0593E05F9EB2/DiveLog/p6> ; data: {
    current = nil;
    depth = 0;
    "dive_at" = "0xd000000000140000 <x-coredata://2B6F1E6F-1EDA-4910-91FA-0593E05F9EB2/DiveSite/p5>";
    id = nil;
    latitude = 0;
    longitude = 0;
    rating = 5;
    "sea_condition" = nil;
    temperature = 0;
    time = nil;
    weather = nil;
})
raw dive site rating is 5.35679601527854e-315
dive rating is 1.06203402623994e-314
dive site rating is 1.06203402623994e-314
```

The DiveLog object in swift is as below. I really do not have a clue about this. It seems that something is out of bound while getting the rating properties?

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

extension DiveLog {

    @NSManaged var time: NSDate?
    @NSManaged var latitude: NSNumber?
    @NSManaged var id: String?
    @NSManaged var rating: NSNumber?
    @NSManaged var depth: NSNumber?
    @NSManaged var temperature: NSNumber?
    @NSManaged var weather: String?
    @NSManaged var current: String?
    @NSManaged var sea_condition: String?
    @NSManaged var longitude: NSNumber?
    @NSManaged var dive_at: DiveSite?

}
```

Comment: I see that you are using NSNumber. Is there any reason for that when you're able to use the Swift Double type directly? Also, I believe that you should access the NSNumber value with rating.doubleValue. You can't access it directly.

Comment: can't it be that the value is just supposed to be 0 (and that is a reasonable approximation)?

Comment: Since `rating` is an optional, what happens if you print `dive.rating!`?

Comment: @VojtaStavik The file was generated by the XCode. It's actually the class+CoreDataProperties.swift file. I did not have any problem with NSNumber with past projects, though...

Comment: @TomHarrington I changed to dive.rating! Here's output on the console...
<ScubaDoo.DiveLog: 0x7fa92df104e0> (entity: DiveLog; id: 0xd0000000002c0000 <x-coredata://2B6F1E6F-1EDA-4910-91FA-0593E05F9EB2/DiveLog/p11> ; data: {
    current = nil;
    depth = 0;
    "dive_at" = "0xd0000000000c0002 <x-coredata://2B6F1E6F-1EDA-4910-91FA-0593E05F9EB2/DiveSite/p3>";
    id = nil;
    latitude = 0;
    longitude = 0;
    rating = 5;
    "sea_condition" = nil;
    temperature = 0;
    time = nil;
    weather = nil;
})
raw dive site rating is 5.35679601527854e-315
dive rating is 0.0
dive site rating is 0.0

Comment: @DavideDeFranceschi So, I checked with the line 'print(dive)', and the console showed that the rating was actually '5' (at least, in the sqlite database).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what just happened, but I upgraded to XCode 7.3, and somehow the problem was fixed. I guessed the issue was with the IDE itself?